# JQuery jqGrid vertical spacing issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I have been developing an app to use jQuery's jqGrid plugin, and I thought I had it all wrapped up until I tried to view the grid in IE.  In IE, the grid appears with a much larger height in the .ui-jqgrid-view div, but the data itself stays at a smaller size and displays at the bottom of the container div (.ui-jqgrid-view).  I need to get the grid to display "properly".  I don't care if it is the larger size (that IE displays) or smaller (as in FF)... I just need to have the data fill the grid area.  Thanks!

I uploaded a screenshot: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTNtk.jpg)

Grid Code:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
            url: gDataPath,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'VId', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'MId'],
            colModel: [
      { name: 'ID1', index: 'ID1', width: 75, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'VID', index: 'VID', width: 75, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 225, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 225, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'MIDno', index: 'MIDno', width: 260, align: 'left'}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [50, 100, 200, 500],
            sortname: 'ID1',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: 'http://mysite/Content/images',
            caption: 'Project Name Data',
            ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol) {
                var i = jQuery("#list").getRowData(rowid);
                window.location = '<%=linkPath %>/'+ i.VisitID;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `<table id="list"></table>` as container. I don't think divs is proper container for jqGrid. Then you can wrap the table tag within any div.